# How to view inverses of morphisms under semigroups and monoids

Tags: abstract-algebra, semigroups, monoid

I know this is a basic question, but given a morphism $f:M \rightarrow N$, where $M$ and $N$ are say, monoids. For any $
\{a,b\} \in M$, we have $f(ab)=f(a)f(b)$ from the definition of a morphism.

Now, let $\{c,d\} \in N$, and $f^{-1}$ as the inverse of $f$, does the statement below follow in general ?

$$
f^{-1}(cd)=f^{-1}(c)f^{-1}(d)
$$

Comment: @Arthur, $f^{-1}$ is inverse as a morphism

Comment: If $f$ is a homomorphism of groups, rings, monoids, etc. and it has a two-sided inverse as a map of sets, then that inverse is also a homomorphism.